# What is wrong with this If/Else code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a "Change" button that makes a form active or locked when clicked. Though the button only works when I click "change", and then doesn't :/

```
<div class="holder">
  <div class="question active">Q1<input id="one" type="text">
<div class="button passive"><input type="button" value="Change" id="changeone"></div></div></div>

$('input#changeone').click(function() {
    if( $('#one').attr('readonly', true) ) {

      $("#changeone").attr('value', 'Save');
      $('div.button').parent().css('background-color', 'red');
      $('#one').attr('readonly', false);

    } else {

      $("#changeone").attr('value', 'Change');
      $('div.button').parent().css('background-color', 'green');
      $('#one').attr('readonly', true);

    }

})
```

THANKS :)

**corrected indentation

THANK YOU ALL! You all responded so quickly and I thank everyone for their time :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are *setting* `readonly` to `true` in your `if`, rather than *getting* it. You need to use [`.attr(attributeName)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get the value.

```
$('input#changeone').click(function() {
    if( $('#one').attr('readonly') == 'readonly') {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: So should it look like this( $('#one').attr(readonly) = true ) { ?

Comment: It depends, the correct _readonly_ attribute should be set as `readonly="readonly"` in the markup, so a positive test is `attr('readonly') == 'readonly'`. However as @Mrchief has pointed out there could be a standalone attribute (not valid XHTML). If you are in control of setting the readonly attribute correctly, then the comparison above will do just fine.

Answer (score 5):

Need to check for true like this:

```
if( $('#one').attr('readonly') == true) )
```

You can also just have readonly attribute by itself

```
<input readonly>
```

In that case, use this:

```
$('#one').is('[readonly="readonly"]') || $('#one').is('[readonly="true"]')
```

Combining the two into single statement:

```
var isReadonly = $('#one').attr("readonly");
if(isReadonly && isReadonly.toLowerCase()!=='false') { 
   // this is readonly
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('input#changeone').click(function() {
    if( $('#one').attr('readonly')) {

    $("#changeone").attr('value', 'Save');
    $('div.button').parent().css('background-color', 'red');
    $('#one').attr('readonly', false);

} else {

    $("#changeone").attr('value', 'Change');
    $('div.button').parent().css('background-color', 'green');
    $('#one').attr('readonly', true);

}

})
```

Answer (score 2):

try this one

```
<div class="holder">
  <div class="question active">Q1<input id="one" type="text">
<div class="button passive"><input type="button" value="Change" id="changeone"></div></div></div>

$('input#changeone').click(function() {
    if( $('#one').attr('readonly') == true ) {

    $("#changeone").attr('value', 'Save');
    $('div.button').parent().css('background-color', 'red');
    $('#one').attr('readonly', false);

} else {

    $("#changeone").attr('value', 'Change');
    $('div.button').parent().css('background-color', 'green');
    $('#one').attr('readonly', true);

}

})
```

Answer (score 2):

`$('#one').attr('readonly', true)` sets the `readonly` attribute to `true`. You need to read it and compare it with `true`

```
if ($('#one').attr('readonly') == true) // ...
```

Answer (score 2):

should be

$('input#changeone').click(function() {
    if( $('#one').attr('readonly') ) {

```
  $("#changeone").attr('value', 'Save');
  $('div.button').parent().css('background-color', 'red');
  $('#one').attr('readonly', false);

} else {

  $("#changeone").attr('value', 'Change');
  $('div.button').parent().css('background-color', 'green');
  $('#one').attr('readonly', true);

}
```

})

instead